# catching 413 errors in flask application with error handlers

Tags: python, flask, exception, werkzeug

I wrote a general error handler for a flask application like this

```
def error_handler(error):
    if isinstance(error, HTTPException):
        description = error.get_description(request.environ)
        code = error.code
        name = error.name
    else:
        description = ("We encountered an error "
                       "while trying to fulfill your request")
        code = 500
        name = 'Internal Server Error'

    templates_to_try = ['errors/error{}.html'.format(code), 'errors/generic_error.html']
    return render_template(templates_to_try,
                           code=code,
                           name=Markup(name),
                           description=Markup(description),
                           error=error)


def init_app(app):
    ''' Function to register error_handler in app '''
    for exception in default_exceptions:
        app.register_error_handler(exception, error_handler)

    app.register_error_handler(Exception, error_handler)
```

which I registered with the app as

```
error_handler.init_app(app)
```

but in case of a 413 error (Request Entity Too Large) I do not get redirected to the error handler? Instead, I can create an additional error handler like this

```
@app.errorhandler(413)
def request_entity_too_large(error):
    return 'File Too Large', 413
```

which catches the error fine.
I found that when I raise the RequestEntityTooLarge error artificially within my app, the error handler works fine. So it must have to do with the fact that the error gets raise within the werkzeuge package

```
    RequestBase._load_form_data(self)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 385, in _load_form_data
    mimetype, content_length, options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/formparser.py", line 197, in parse
    raise exceptions.RequestEntityTooLarge()
RequestEntityTooLarge: 413 Request Entity Too Large: The data value transmitted exceeds the capacity limit.
```

Does anybody know why my first solution cannot capture 413 errors? But my second solution can? How would I need to modify my error_handler to capture the 413 error?

Answer (score 0):

ok I found the solution. Changing the error_handler to

```
return render_template(templates_to_try,
                       code=code,
                       name=Markup(name),
                       description=Markup(description),
                       error=error), code
```

does solve the problem... not sure exactly why though

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the flask development server. It is not really a fully fledged server and falls short in that aspect. You don't have to worry about it because in production WSGI server etc it will work as expected with a normal error handler. 
To quote flask documentation:

> When using the local development server, you may get a connection
>   reset error instead of a 413 response. You will get the correct status
>   response when running the app with a production WSGI server.